# iOS Collections and Tables - asynchronously calculating cell values

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uicollectionview

I've been working on an app that involves some fairly heavy but variable calculations for cell contents. I approached this several different ways, with a lot of bad results. I finally found a good solution, but I decided to post this for discussion and critique.

My particular problem was that I have a calendar that can display between 1 and 365 cells, and each cell displays eight values that must be calculated on the fly. (Some limited caching of values is possible, but I discovered quickly that the data made full caching impossible.) The full calculation chain was taking up to 30 seconds in the worst case scenario I tried, but then this can increase with more complex data sets. Clearly, simply calculating the values at the time the cell is created created an unacceptable lag and worse still, an unresponsive interface. (The following code has been simplified of course.)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (_typeOfLayout) {
        case BACalendarLayoutTypeDay:
        {
            BAPeriod *period = [BAPeriod newWithSingular:_date];
            BACalendarViewCell * cell = (BACalendarViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:BACalendarCellKind forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.period = period;
            BAPeriod * periodToDate = [[period preceding] union:period];

            cell.value1 = [_modelInterface totalValue1:periodToDate];
            cell.value2 = [_modelInterface totalValue2:periodToDate];
            ...

            return cell;
        }

        case BACalendarLayoutTypeWeek:
        ...
    }
}
```

My first solution this problem involved deferring the calculations to a queue, but this required the calculation chain to be synchronised very carefully and this resulted the cells displaying and then updating the way I wanted. However, it also resulted in random deadlocks and an even longer delay before results were displayed. It was also possible that by the time a value was calculated, the cell might have been removed.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (_typeOfLayout) {
        case BACalendarLayoutTypeDay:
        {
            BAPeriod *period = [BAPeriod newWithSingular:_date];
            BACalendarViewCell * cell = (BACalendarViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:BACalendarCellKind forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.period = period;
            BAPeriod * periodToDate = [[period preceding] union:period];
            cell.valuesAvailableNow = false;

            dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
                cell.value1 = [_modelInterface totalValue1:periodToDate];
                cell.value2 = [_modelInterface totalValue2:periodToDate];
                ...
                cell.valuesAvailableNow = true;
                [cell needsDisplay];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        case BACalendarLayoutTypeWeek:
        ...
    }
}
```

My next solution was forget about the synchronisation and do all the calculation serially on the main queue, but use the queue I had created to manage the calculations. I also started to check whether the cell was still available in case the user had quickly switched to another view. The result was an improvement in time, but the interface was becoming unresponsive after displaying, taking a long time to update the cells with the calculated values, and for some reason sometimes failing to update a cell.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (_typeOfLayout) {
        case BACalendarLayoutTypeDay:
        {
            BAPeriod *period = [BAPeriod newWithSingular:_date];
            BACalendarViewCell * cell = (BACalendarViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:BACalendarCellKind forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.period = period;
            BAPeriod * periodToDate = [[period preceding] union:period];
            cell.valuesAvailableNow = false;

            dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
                dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
                dispatch_group_asynch(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ([self cellStillActive:cell]) {
                        cell.value1 = [_modelInterface totalValue1:periodToDate];
                    }
                });
                dispatch_group_asynch(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    if ([self cellStillActive:cell]) {
                        cell.value2 = [_modelInterface totalValue2:periodToDate];
                    }
                });
                ...
                dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
                cell.valuesAvailableNow = true;
                [cell needsDisplay];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        case BACalendarLayoutTypeWeek:
        ...
    }
}
```

I realised that the problem was that all the calculations were being dumped onto the main queue to be performed in one solid chunk, and new events were being added after them. The final solution, which works very well, was to add execute the calculations SYNCHRONOUSLY in the main thread, and not add a new calculation till the previous one was complete. This allowed system events to be added asynchronously between calculations. The result was good interface responsiveness and excellent calculation.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (_typeOfLayout) {
        case BACalendarLayoutTypeDay:
        {
            BAPeriod *period = [BAPeriod newWithSingular:_date];
            BACalendarViewCell * cell = (BACalendarViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:BACalendarCellKind forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.period = period;
            BAPeriod * periodToDate = [[period preceding] union:period];
            cell.valuesAvailableNow = false;

            dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
                if ([self cellStillActive:cell]) {
                    dispatch_synch(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        cell.value1 = [_modelInterface totalValue1:periodToDate];
                    });
                }
                if ([self cellStillActive:cell]) {
                    dispatch_synch(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        cell.value2 = [_modelInterface totalValue2:periodToDate];
                    });
                }
                ...
                cell.valuesAvailableNow = true;
                [cell needsDisplay];
            }

            return cell;
        }

        case BACalendarLayoutTypeWeek:
        ...
    }
}
```

So ... opinions? Other solutions?